# Simple Post and Get C# WPF

Tags: c#, sockets

I have two textboxes and a button.  I want to put something in textBox1, send that to a server and put the results I get back in textBox2.

I can't seem to understand sockets well enough to accomplish this.  I have an address and a port.

Does anyone have just a super simple setup to do this?  Everything I've found includes classes I can't even find namespaces for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to get data from a website:

```
private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
public static async Task<string> GetWebsiteDataAsync(Uri fromUri)
{
    using (var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, fromUri))
    using (var resp = await _client.SendAsync(msg))
    {
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

You would then call it as so:

```
var websiteData = await GetWebsiteDataAsync(new Uri("https://example.com"));
```

Your title asked for Post as well, so here's how you'd do that (requires `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package):

```
public static async Task<TResult> PostObjectToWebsiteAsync<TResult>(
    Uri site, object objToPost)
{
    using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, site))
    {
        req.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objToPost),
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using (var resp = await _client.SendAsync(req))
        {
            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            using (var s = await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            using (var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<TResult>(jtr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you could call that like this:

```
var objToPost = new
{
    hello = "world",
    value = 5
}

var postResonse = await PostObjectToWebsiteAsync<object>(
    new Uri("https://example.com"), objToPost);
```