# How to get all Objects from a big Array by an API (C#)

Tags: c#, json, api, json-deserialization, steam

**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content**

Hello,
I try to get every Object from a big Array provided by an API (steam-API).
I need multiple calls to get all the Objects since they are a  **"total_count":15228**.
This is my method to get the [first page](https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&count=100&start=0), which works perfectly fine:

```
public static Task LoadAllItemsAsync()
        {
            int start=0;
            string responseData = "";
            
                
                using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
                {
                    responseData = responseData + w.DownloadString("https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&count=100&start=" + start);
                    
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    w.Dispose();
                }
                start = start + 100;
            

            

            dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseData);
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\SteamData\SteamItems.json"), jsonData);

            return Task.CompletedTask;

        }
```

And to get all of the Objects, I try to loop through all pages, by increasing the **start value by 100**, and **here is where I get an exception** when I try to deserialize the **responsData** string.
Code:

```
public static Task LoadAllItemsAsync()
        {
            int start=0;
            string responseData = "";
            for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
            {
                
                using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
                {
                    responseData = responseData + w.DownloadString("https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&count=100&start=" + start);
                    
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    w.Dispose();
                }
                start = start + 100;
            }

            

              dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseData); //Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\SteamData\SteamItems.json"), jsonData);

            return Task.CompletedTask;

        }
```

I have found something on google, but I don't understand it and I don't know how to apply it on my code.
I highly appreciate any answers.

Edit: 
What I have tried:

```
public static Task LoadAllItemsAsync()
        {
            int start=0;
            string responseData = "";
            string jsonData = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
            {               
                using (WebClient w = new WebClient())
                {
                    responseData = responseData + w.DownloadString("https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&count=100&start=" + start);
                    dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseData);
                    jsonData = jsonData + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
                    
                }
                start = start + 100;
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\SteamData\SteamItems.json"), jsonData);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Comment: `WebClient` is obsolete/deprecated/legacy -- `HttpClient` is much better at doing what you need. Here is an example on how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289051/simple-post-and-get-c-sharp-wpf/63289143#63289143

Comment: Each API response should be a complete JSON object on its own. I don't think you should be concatenating responses with previous ones and then trying to deserialize once at the end. You should be deserializing each one on its own.

Comment: I know that, but the API has a limit of 20 requests per Minute. So I thought, that I could add all Objects to the application and check if an object is available before I try to get data about that Object, so I don't waste requests on not available Objects.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My suggestion doesn't change the number of API requests. It changes the number of deserializations.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: it does not work because nothing has changed. you should deserialize json to c# object and add it to list of such objects, then you can serialize array of items. currently you append one json string to another which results in invalid json content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following code. The first step is to extract c# types from your json - I used https://json2csharp.com/ for that. Then you should iterate through requests and deserialize each into your objects. Collect all the objects you need in a separate list, serialize and write to file.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;

namespace SteamMarketJson
{
    public class Searchdata
    {
        public string query { get; set; }
        public bool search_descriptions { get; set; }
        public int total_count { get; set; }
        public int pagesize { get; set; }
        public string prefix { get; set; }
        public string class_prefix { get; set; }
    }

    public class AssetDescription
    {
        public int appid { get; set; }
        public string classid { get; set; }
        public string instanceid { get; set; }
        public string background_color { get; set; }
        public string icon_url { get; set; }
        public int tradable { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string name_color { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string market_name { get; set; }
        public string market_hash_name { get; set; }
        public int commodity { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string hash_name { get; set; }
        public int sell_listings { get; set; }
        public int sell_price { get; set; }
        public string sell_price_text { get; set; }
        public string app_icon { get; set; }
        public string app_name { get; set; }
        public AssetDescription asset_description { get; set; }
        public string sale_price_text { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public int start { get; set; }
        public int pagesize { get; set; }
        public int total_count { get; set; }
        public Searchdata searchdata { get; set; }
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        private const string BASE_URL = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?search_descriptions=0&sort_column=default&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&norender=1&count=100&start=";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int start = 0;

            List<Result> results = new List<Result>(); // you probably want to store results only
            
            RootObject rootObject = null;
            do
            {
                var response = httpClient.GetAsync(BASE_URL + start).Result; // use await instead of .Result when used in methods
                var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(body);

                if (rootObject.results != null)
                {
                    results.AddRange(rootObject.results);
                }
                start += 100;

                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            while (start < rootObject.total_count);


            // write to file

            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);

            File.WriteAllText("D:\\file.txt", jsonResult);


            // read and deserialize it back

            var fileContent = File.ReadAllText("D:\\file.txt");

            var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Result>>(fileContent);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a very clean code! But I sometimes get this Exception("Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ?. Path '', line 0, position 0."). But that's probably another topic.

Comment: yeah, would be better to create different question for that